# Has MS Edge started blocking onClick return confirm javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I have a an html form with code similar to:

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit" name="somevariablename" value="somevariablevalue" onClick="return(confirm('Are you SURE you want to do this thing?'));">click</button>
</form>
```

When the customer uses MS Edge and they click the button, they report that nothing happens and the form is not submitted. When I had them try a different browser (Chrome) it worked fine: they got the pop-up, they clicked OK, and the form submitted.

**Can anyone think of something else that might be blocking the javascript onClick return confirm from working?
Is there some new default security policy for MS Edge and windows 11 that might do this?**

I have not been able to reproduce this issue for myself. It is a customer who is having this issue with my html.

The same html page works fine on my copy of MS Edge and the customer says they only started having this issue after they got a new computer. They are using Windows 11, I am using Windows 10.

I tried going to my Edge settings edge://settings/content/javascript?search=javascript and turning off JavaScript. This blocked the pop-up confirmation **but the form submitted as though I had clicked [OK]** while the customer's form does not submit.

Comment: No repro with Edge here on Win11. Do they have any extensions installed?

Comment: Unfortunately, the customer is not able to tell me much. I'm waiting to hear back from them about their Edge javascript settings, I'll try to find out about extensions when they get back to me.

Comment: FYI: return is not a method.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on Win11 either. Might be related with extensions, you can ask them to try in InPrivate window. Besides, you can go to *edge://policy/* check if they have configured any gpo which might cause an issue.